# How to make a Jenkins job status as aborted

Tags: hudson, jenkins

I am running some batch commands as a prebuild step for a build. I want to make the status of the build as aborted based on some conditions.

Can anyone tell me what is the errorlevel for 'aborted' in Jenkins?

Answer (score 26):

You have to install the "[Conditional build step plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin)" and the "[Fail the build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Fail+The+Build+Plugin)" plugins. Then you simply add a conditional step, and if the condition is true, you can call the fail build step with state "aborted".