# How do I abort the current job?

Tags: jenkins

When my job is running, under some conditions I want to cancel or abort the current job. I don't want it to succeed or fail (since these send emails and update code reviews etc), I just want it to quit quickly.

Preferably, I want to abort from within a shell script build action (a special exit-code would be perfect), but I'll take what I can get.

Comment: Updated my answer.  If the linked question and answer are good for you, would you like to close this question as a duplicate of that one?

Comment: Go ahead and close as a dupe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a Jenkins job status as aborted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488541/how-to-make-a-jenkins-job-status-as-aborted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While looking for a plugin that would help, I stumbled across the duplicate question [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488541/how-to-make-a-jenkins-job-status-as-aborted).

It recommends the [Conditional BuildStep Plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) working with the [Fail The Build Plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Fail+The+Build+Plugin)

Does that answer your question?

Comment: I need a way for the job to cancel itself.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for, but I couldn't find it even after searching for cancel/abort/stop etc. with the jenkins tag.